# Square’s Point of Sale IOS SDK

Tags: square-connect

I integrated this into my app but right now I specify a dollar amount in the SCCAPIRequest and instead need to specify an item. Even if the dollar amount is the same, we need inventory and analytics to be kept accurate by selling an item in the POS, not a magic number in USD.

Is there any way to do this. I don’t see it in the documentation but seems like it should be available somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Square POS API does not support itemization, and therefore cannot have items passed to it.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/pos/overview

Comment: I was afraid of that. The API is otherwise awesome but losing the ability to track inventory or maintain accurate sales reports excludes it from a lot of use cases. Anyway, thanks for chiming in.

Comment: It should be possible to create an Order (with itemization) and pass the `order_id` via the notes field, but then you would need to go back and edit the inventory yourself. It's not something we recommend or test per se, but it should be plausible.